# WCF development on 32bit pc and using on 64bit

Tags: c#, wcf

I will be developing WCF app, fortunately the laptop that I have can work in 32bit not 64bit. And I will be using the app on a 64bit server machine.

For it I would like to ask if there is anything I need to do for it to work on both sides with no issues.

thanks,

Comment: If you are using compile default **any CPU** then i think it won't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed few WCF-based applications on my 32-bit machine, all of them worked fine on 64-bit servers (windows server 2008). So just go ahead and deploy.

The communication part (bindings etc) absolutely must work regardless of platforms on both ends. There might be some problems with using on 32-bit machine DLLs that were compiled to 64bit, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is designed to be portable, *certainly* .NET-to-.NET (without needing to know the machine's config), but usually also between OS/VM/language/architecture too.

You shouldn't need to change anything; it should *just work*.